# Automatically assign different static IP address for each standard user on one home/office windows 7 PC

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-accounts, group-policy

I have a PC on my office that i have windows 7 ultimate installed on it,
Me and my colleague wanted to use this PC with different user accounts and each of us have a static IP that must be set on its Ethernet adapter, so we connect to the network with different IP address.

My account has Administrator privilege and his account is Standard User, if i set my IP address in my account he will get that IP too but as i said i wanted him to use his own IP address automatically.
We use "Switch User" in window login screen to log into our account every time any one of us wanted to use this PC.
How can i setup accounts for this purpose?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, find another way to do it that doesn't require associating users with IP addresses.  Windows services use the network too, and changing the IP address underneath them when you switch users is going to cause a great big mess.

Comment: Ben Voigt, Thank you, i wanted to be sure that this is not possible, now i will find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Try incomputing if you have enough Performance in your PC,